# Using php/javascript to make 3 dependent drop down menus that are populated from a MySQL database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Using php/javascript to make 3 dependent drop down menus that are populated from a MySQL database

Hi! I am new to coding/web development. I know this is a popular topic and I have already spent hours reading forums and looking at sample code, however:

a) Examples I have found include data that is hard-coded and does not pull the data from a database, which is what I need to do.
b) The examples also use extentions like mysql_query and mysql_fetch_assoc which are now deprecated. I think I need to use PDO but I am unfamiliar with that.

Here is some background about my database:

There is only one table in the database--"costs_table." The fields that I am trying to populate the  drop downs with are "Subsystem," ,"Unit_Cost_element" and "Unit_Cost_component." There is a 1:M relationship between these fields- a subsystem has many elements, and an element has many components.

Here is the SQL statements for what I want the code to be doing for each drop down:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Subsytem FROM Costs_table;

SELECT DISTINCT Unit_Cost_Element FROM Costs_Table WHERE Subsystem = $SelectedSubsystem;

SELECT DISTINCT Unit_Cost_Component FROM Costs_Table WHERE Subsystem = $SelectedSubsystem AND Unit_Cost_Element = $SelectedElement;
```

I know I will eventually need arrays but I have never constructed an array before. The code I have so far is just the index page that creates the list boxes. Also I got this code from another forum so it may not be 100% in-line with what I need to do.

Anyways here is the code:

```
<?php

try {
    $objDb = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=unit_costs_db', 'username', 'password');
    $objDb->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Subsystem, ID FROM costs_table ORDER BY Subsystem ASC";
    $statement = $objDb->query($sql);
    $list = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}
    catch(PDOException $e){
    echo 'There was a problem';
        }
    ?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="en"
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title> Dependable Dropdown menu</title>
<meta name="description" content="Dependable dropdown menu" />
<meta name="keywords" content="dependable dropdown menu" />
<link href="/css/6-19_core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>


<body>


<div id="wrapper">
    <form action="" method="post">

            <select name="Subsystem" id="Subsystem" class="update">
                <option value="">Select Subsystem</option>
                <?php if (!empty($list)) { 
                    foreach($list as $row) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">
                        <?php echo $row['Subsystem']; ?>
                    </option>
                <?php }
                }
                ?>
                </select>

            </select>
                <br>
            <select name="Element" id="Element" class="update"
                disabled="disabled">
                <option value="">----</option>
            </select>
                <br>
            <select name="Component" id="Component" class="update"
                disabled="disabled">
                <option value="">----</option>
            </select>

    </form>
</div>




<script src="/js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/js/6-19_core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help with what I need to add to make this work properly would be greatly appreciated!!! Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

[More on PDO prepared statements.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

I am a relative novice with PHP/PDO, so if this answer can be improved, please let me know how.

Firstly, your connection needs to be improved. Use this:

```
try {
$objDb = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=databaseName', 'user', 'password');
$objDb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$objDb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

[Read more on connections](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)

You need to use the `execute` object :) I would wrap it in a function. Something like this:

The function is written after your `try` closing brace `}`.

```
function querySelection($objDb,$sql) {
    $statement = $objDb->prepare($sql); #prepare
    $statement->execute(); #execute 
    $list = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach($list as $row) {
        echo '<option value=" ' . $row['ID'] . ' "> ' . $row['Subsystem'] . '</option>';
    }

}
```

In your form:

```
<select>
    <option value="0">----</option>
    <?php 
        $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT Subsystem, ID FROM costs_table ORDER BY Subsystem ASC';
        querySelection($objDb,$sql); 
        # $objDb passes the database connection variable to the function 
        # $sql passes the query
    ?>
</select>

Continue for each query...


<select>
    <option value="0">----</option>
    <?php 
        $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT Subsytem FROM Costs_table';
        querySelection($objDb,$sql); 
        # $objDb passes the database connection variable to the function 
        # $sql passes the query
    ?>
</select>
```

...etc